# Does routesImport work for parameters types in Playframework-2.x?

Tags: playframework-2.2

To be more specific, I am trying to omit "java.lang" in routes like

```
GET     /users/profile/:userId              controllers.Users.getProfile(userId: java.util.UUID)
```

Unfortunately,

```
routesImport += "java.util.UUID"
```

in build.sbt doesn't work, and if I specify "UUID" instead of "java.lang.UUID" I get "not found: type UUID"

So, is it possible to import some types and then use just type name in routes, instead of specifying full package name each time?

Comment: I've gotten this to work for some classes but not others. `java.util.UUID` doesn't work for me, but when I defined custom types, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

`routesImport` doesn't work for the `routes` file. The Controller methods and parameters need to be fully qualified. The only exceptions (I think) would actually be your example of `java.lang.*` and probably `scala.*`. So you can do `String foo` instead of `java.lang.String foo`, but classes in any other package will need to be fully qualified each time.

Comment: Is there no way around this? It's really ugly to have to fully qualify everything.

Comment: @cdmckay As far as I know that's still the case. There's a bit more info on [this Google Group thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/k5MT68xFzDA/discussion) about what `routesImport` is meant for. I guess the fully qualified names are needed for the reverse router parsing.